# website.php#footer?variable="value" is this possible?

Tags: php, html

When I was using this href link `website.php#footer?variable="value"` the variable value doesn't show up? or this is not possible?

the "#footer" is an anchor id so when you click an  tag it will scrolldown to the selected div with an id of "footer". I want to pass a variable from one page to another by using "?variable="value"".

But when I combined those two it doesn't work. Thank you in advance.

Comment: **Everything** after the `#` is considered a fragment and is not interpreted by the server. Put your query params first, ie `website.php?variable=value#footer`

Comment: Thank you! I now understand how to do it. Thank you so much again.